# How to create a user after ldap authenticaion?

Tags: authentication-authorization

I am using ldap for Drupal 7.  After successfully authenticating, how do I create a Drupal user.

Comment: People -> add? Or what exactly are you trying to ask?

Answer (score 1):

The LDAP module will also allow you to automatically create a user after authentication.

- Once you configure your server, look at the third tab LDAP
  authorization Choose edit to configure that server
- Under basic, enable and Only apply the following LDAP to drupal role
  configuration to users authenticated via LDAP.
- You can set the role of the new user by checking  drupal roles are
  specified by LDAP attributes under IIB. Also name the field that will
  be use to determine role
- Configure part III. LDAP to drupal role mapping and filtering For
  example, if the title field is Staff you may want to give a staff
  role Staff|staff
- Part 4    IV.B. When should drupal roles be granted/revoked from
  user? Check "When a user logs on"
- IV.C. What actions would you like performed when drupal roles are
  granted/revoked from user? Check Revoke drupal roles previously
  granted by LDAP Authorization but no longer valid.

There are other settings that you can configure but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

the [Ldap](http://drupal.org/project/ldap) and [Simple LDAP](http://drupal.org/project/simple_ldap) modules both can create Drupal user accounts for you after authentication. Read the project documentation and readme files.

For example from the Simple Ldap project page:

> Simple LDAP User
>
> This module allows authentication to the LDAP directory configured in
>   the Simple LDAP module. It also provides synchronization services both
>   to and from LDAP and Drupal. It supports mapping LDAP attributes to
>   Drupal user object fields (both native, and using Field API).